# AWS Skill builder certification: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate

Anyone knows why the AWS skill builder don't allow me to download my certificate?

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>files/a/w/aws_prod1_docebosaas_com/certificate/</Key>
<RequestId>KTKYNDBHW9235KXY</RequestId>
<HostId>ALGHhV5YoaTdzUNmm95vtcCuiTmPP4rdCkXlWKRkeSjNNciEzTlMyFzsXK2FU5J/LxebCTlCnAg=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I want to upload on my LinkedIn profile

It seems weird because I downloaded certificates before, I was like refresh the page all the time when I come again to the page but it still doesn't work!